# Additivity in ring of subsets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $R$ be a ring of subsets of a set $X$, and let $\mu$ be a measure defined on $R$. Let $\mu^*$ be the corresponding outer measure. Prove that if $A\in R$, then $\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A^c\cap E)=\mu^*(E)$ for all $E\subseteq X$.

Well, we clearly have $\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A^c\cap E)\geq\mu^*(E)$ because $\mu^*$ is subadditive. Now, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a cover $B_1,B_2,\ldots\in R$ of $E$ such that $\mu(B_1)+\mu(B_2)+\ldots=\mu^*(E)+\epsilon$. I want to look at the covering $A\cap B_1,A\cap B_2,\ldots$ of $A$, and the covering $A^c\cap B_1,A^c\cap B_2,\ldots$ of $A^c$. The trouble is: $A^c$ might not belong to the ring (the ring is closed under union and set difference.) So we don't know if $A^c\cap B_1\in R$. How can we get around this?

Comment: Note: $B_1 \cap A^c = B_1 \setminus A = B_1 \setminus (A\cap B_1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do know that $A^c \cap B_1 \in R$, since that is the set difference of $B_1$ and $A$. By definition, $X\setminus Y = X \cap Y^c$, where the complement may be taken with respect to any ambient universe. Since a ring of sets is closed under set difference, $X\cap Y^c \in R$ for all $X,Y\in R$.